# how to find the biggest possible Y point given X in Region in Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-graphics

[image]

I have a virtual ruler being drawn on the screen. I want to be able to draw a straight line like the blue line above when touch event happen within the grown rectangle. but because touch can't be 100% straight, the movement might be like the red line. that's why I set a rectangle to listen to all the nearby touch events then draw a blue line.

I currently have

```
mRulerRect.set(mRulerCenter.x - mRulerBitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                mRulerCenter.y - mRulerBitmap.getHeight()),
                mRulerCenter.x + mRulerBitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                mRulerCenter.y);
mPath.addRect(mRulerRect, Path.Direction.CCW);
mRulerMatrix.setRotate(mRulerAngle, mRulerCenter.x, mRulerCenter.y);
mPath.transform(mRulerMatrix);
mRegions.setPath(mPath, new Region(mRulerRect));
```

then I check if the touch even happen within brown rectangle by `mRegions.contains(x,y)`. works perfect so far for touch detection, but the problem I have now is how to draw a straight line. I tried to fix X point then calculate Y. it works fine when ruler is horizontal then starts to behave very weird when turning from horizontal to vertical. I'm out of idea how to accomplish this. Please help! thank you.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand the problem, you get touch coordinates that are within that brown rect, and then you want to draw a line that pass from there and is parallel to the ruler..?

Comment: @lelloman yes! that is correct, but since move event might happen like the red line, how can I draw the blue line that is parallel to the ruler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things that you know:

- The center of that brown rect is `mRulerCenter.x, mRulerCenter.y`
- The line that you want to draw pass through that point
- The angle of the line is `mRulerAngle`

We're missing just one element, which is, the length of the line we want to draw. That's probably going to be a portion of the ruler's width and it should be very easy to compute `mRulerRect.width() * someFactor`

Now, we want to know what are the start and the end of the line, we can compute that with trigonometry functions

```
float halfLineLength = mRulerRect.width() * someFactor;
float startAngle = (float) Math.toRadians(mRulerAngle);
float endAngle = (float) Math.toRadians(mRulerAngle + 180);

float startX = mRulerCenter.x + (float) Math.cos(startAngle) * halfLineLength;
float startY = mRulerCenter.y + (float) Math.sin(startAngle) * halfLineLength;

float endX = mRulerCenter.x + (float) Math.cos(endAngle) * halfLineLength;
float endY = mRulerCenter.y + (float) Math.sin(endAngle) * halfLineLength;
```

and then draw your line from (startX, startY) to (endX, endY), actually doesn't really matter which is start and which is end

Comment: I dont understand where I can plug in the x,y point that touched by user?

Comment: right, the code I posted is to draw the blue line in the picture with its center on the center of the brown rect. do you want the center of the line to correspond to the touch?

Comment: assume i have width and height of the ruler. is it possible to draw the blue line right on top of the ruler image?

Comment: the brown Rect is just used to give some tolerance since it is impossible to have human touch a straight line. the center of brown rect isn't necessary to be right on top of ruler

Comment: yes you can draw it on top of the ruler, the code i posted will use mRulerCenter x and y as center of the line because that's the point you're rotating the ruler around, you can choose another point if you want

Comment: oh, so does that mean if i replace mRulerCenter with the actual touch point, it'll work? let me try it now

Comment: mRulerCenter x and y are the center of the line that will be drawn, and the angle is the same as the ruler, so yes it should work

Comment: hummm...line isnt drawn straight. but thank you! your solution inspire me some ideas i can try.

Comment: you're welcome! if I may give you an advice, sin and cos functions are extremely useful for drawing, if the code isn't 100% clear try to google these 2 functions

Comment: yea man. thank you so much! being struggle for days for this.